# How to confirm if the series is stationary?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity

Visually, the below plot doesn't seem to be stationary.

However, on differencing, I am not very sure if the time series is stationary. Visually, it's not.

Please suggest any statistical techniques to confirm

[image]

Comment: Hi, this isn't really a programming question about `r` given that you haven't provided any code or data. You probably want to look into the `adf test` though.

Comment: Looks pretty stationary to me, but with only 17 data points it's hard to tell, even for a test, unless it is really quite nonstationary (e.g., a trend upwards of 2 units/period would probably do it for this data.)

Comment: You probably want to learn about *tests for unit root* (e.g., [KPSS test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KPSS_test), etc.), and about *tests for stationarity* (e.g., [Aumented Dickey-Fuller test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test), etc.).